# Remove next row cell if rowspan is found

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to loop through table in every tr if td have csstdgreen and have attribute rowspan.
I have to remove cell have text Remove Me.

```
   function clearTable()
     {
        if ($("tr").has("td.csstdgreen").length > 0)
        {
            if ($('td[rowSpan]') == 1 || $('td[rowSpan]') == 2 || $('td[rowSpan]') == 3)
            {
                var $this = $(this);
                var i = $this.index();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hint: `$('td[rowSpan]')` will _never_ equal 1, 2 or 3, it will always be an object. If you're trying to get the value of the `rowspan` attribute try `$('td[rowspan]').attr("rowspan")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table tr').each(function(){

    var indexofThis,indexofColSpan,numRows;
    if($('td[rowspan]',this).length!=0)
    {
            indexofThis =$('table tr').index(this);
            indexofColSpan = $('td',this).index($('td[rowspan]',this));
            numRows = $('td[rowspan]',this).attr('rowspan');

            $('table tr:gt('+indexofThis+')').each(function(){
            $('td:eq('+indexofColSpan+')',this).remove();
});
    }
});
​
```

this should give you a helping hand to get what you need. JS fiddle is not working for me atm.
there is a little tinkering to do as it does not do the number of rows, so it will do the whole grid. but this is the main part done.