# If rowspan 3 is found remove 3rd cell of next and next tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove next row cell if rowspan is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373116/remove-next-row-cell-if-rowspan-is-found)

**Table Before removing 3rd cell of tr**

```
<table id="mytable" runat="server" bgcolor="gray">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="csstablelisttd">
            <td></td>
            <td class="csstdgreen">30</td>
            <td class="csstdgreen" rowspan="3">
                <span>john</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="csstablelisttd">
            <td></td>
            <td class="csstdgreen">45</td>
            <td>Remove me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="csstablelisttd">
            <td>09:00</td>
            <td class="csstdgreen">00</td>
            <td>Remove me</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have to loop through table in every tr if td have csstdgreen and have attribute rowspan.
I have to remove cell have text Remove Me.

```
function clearTable() {
    $('#mytable tbody tr td.csstdgreen').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('rowspan')) {
            $(this).parent().find('td:last').remove();
        }
    });
}
```

** I have to make table like this **

```
<table id="mytable" runat="server" bgcolor="gray">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="csstablelisttd">
            <td></td>
            <td class="csstdgreen">30</td>
            <td class="csstdgreen" rowspan="3">
                <span>john</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="csstablelisttd">
            <td></td>
            <td class="csstdgreen">45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="csstablelisttd">
            <td>09:00</td>
            <td class="csstdgreen">00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373116/remove-next-row-cell-if-rowspan-is-found ? `:))` same question again? <might be>

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GNwFU/5/)**

This will search table with id `mytable` for `td` having `class csstdgreen` and `rowspan 3`. If found it will remove the `last td` in all siblings(tr).

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('#mytable td.csstdgreen[rowspan=3]').each(function() {

        $(this).parent().siblings().each(function() {
            $(this).find('td').last().remove();
        });
    });
});
```

​
​

Comment: "Remove Me" text was just to help tell u which cells need to be removed, but they need to be removed because they follow a cell that had a rowspan defined

Comment: There is the attribute selector as well. Also, this simply remvoes any td as soon as it hits the if.

Comment: Check it now and what selector attribute, I have already take rowspan in condition.

Comment: i have to check in whole table for td if rowspan =3

Comment: Check if it is what you want?

Comment: You can use `td.csstdgreen[rowspan='3']` in your selector to account for the rowspan attribute. (That's the attribute selector.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to consider the value of the rowspan as well, try this:

```
$('table tr td.csstdgreen').each(function() {
  // parse attribute
  var rowspan = isNaN($(this).attr('rowspan')) ? 1 : parseInt($(this).attr('rowspan'));
  if (rowspan > 1) {
    var rows = $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, rowspan - 1); // limit elements
    $(rows).find('td:last-child').remove(); // remove last td of each row
  }
});​
```